# can't get the toggle function to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jQuery and am experimenting with some  plugins. I found one called jQuery Balloon. When I add my script and run the code the bubble pops up but won't go away.

Here is my code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.balloon.min.js"></script>
```

Here is my jQuery code. I omitted the `document.ready` because I have that at the top of my document already.

```
 $("a").click(function(event){
   $(this).showBalloon().toggle();
    event.preventDefault();
```

How do I get the balloon popup when the user clicks the link and have it go away when they click away from it?

Comment: chances are you're misusing the balloon plugin wrong.  Please post a link to its source.

Comment: Is showBalloon() returning the jq object?

Comment: (Consider adding a `jsfiddle` as well)

Comment: http://file.urin.take-uma.net/jquery.balloon.js-Demo.html#cite_note-0

Comment: your usage does not match with the example of click handler given in the demo

Comment: @ArunPJohny and the click handler in the demo is using the now-non-existent `.toggle(fn1, fn2)` function.

Comment: what is the jquery verison used

Comment: I tried adding a fiddle and it's giving me problem's linking to the plugin

Comment: @Alnitak I was supposed to ask the jQuery version as a separate comment but teh 15 sec rule prevented it.. so that I could suggest the a different option or suggest the clickToggle() implementation

Comment: @Arun P johny: 1.10.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('a').on('click', ( function balloonState(){
  var state = true;

  return function(ev) {
      var $this = $(this);

      if (state) {
          $this.showBalloon();
      } else {
          $this.hideBalloon();
      }

      state = !state;

      ev.preventDefault();
  } 
}() ) );
```

Alnitak's answer is functionally perfect as far as the question goes, but you can achieve the same with simple native closures (without having to use `$.fn.data`), the advantages being:

- Saving on code execution by avoiding jQuery's DOM-associated data binding and only declaring `state` once
- Avoid needlessly saving state in the DOM, where other code can tamper with it

**EDIT:** As Alnitak pointed out in the comments, an immediately invoked closure would only create one `state` variable for *all* `<a>`s. Assuming that's not what's desired, we can use jQuery's each to create a closure for each `<a>`:

```
$('a').each( function balloonState(){
  var state = true;
  var $this = $( this );

  $this.on( 'click', function(ev) {
      if (state) {
          $this.showBalloon();
      } else {
          $this.hideBalloon();
      }

      state = !state;

      ev.preventDefault();
  } );
} );
```

**EDIT 2:** The method above has the caveat that it will create a new function for each link on the page at runtime, which is very wasteful in terms of memory management and speedy initialization. [The plugin homepage uses the old jQuery `toggle` method to get around the problem of when to execute `hideBalloon` and `showBalloon`](http://file.urin.take-uma.net/jquery.balloon.js-Demo.html#advanced-methods), but [this was deprecated in jQuery 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/). Overall I'd recommend using [Alnitak's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20352251/356541).

Comment: I accepted your answer but there is a bug i want to point out to you, instead of $this.hideBalloon you should change it to $this.showBalloon

Comment: @user3052886 ah! Well spotted. Fixed.

Comment: horses for courses, as they say.  The disadvantage of this method is that every `a` shares the same state.  That's fine if it's what the OP requires, but I rather suspect that the OP wants independent balloons for each link.

Comment: @Alnitak oops! That's actually very important and significantly screws functionality — well spotted.

Comment: ok, now the problem you have is that you're actually creating an entire new function object with its own execution scope (for closing over the state variable) for every single link.  This is far worse than just using `.data`, IMHO.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42421/discussion-between-barney-and-alnitak)

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to track the popup's state, since the `.toggle(fn1, fn2)` function is now [deprecated](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11786):

```
$('a').on('click', function(ev) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var state = !$this.data('balloon');  // use .data, initially undefined
    if (state) {
        $this.hideBalloon();
    } else {
        $this.showBalloon();
    }
    $this.data('balloon', state);
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

Note that this will maintain a separate state for each `a` link.

Comment: +1 don't you want to negate the value of state before setting it back